# How can I install both chrome and chromium on same ubuntu environment

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, chromium

Is it possible to install both chrome and chromium on same ubuntu environment?
I would like to experiment new features in chromium but want to keep chrome on daily use.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Google Chrome and Chromium from the Ubuntu archive use different locations for their profiles, so you can run both and they don't step on each other at all.

The Chromium that ships in the Ubuntu archive is based off of the stable release of Chrome, so if you want something more bleeding edge the Chromium team [provides PPAs](https://launchpad.net/~chromium-daily) of stable, beta, dev, and daily builds of Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

If you (ever) manage to do `configure --prefix`, a same user profile may get corrupted by using both;